# Header component doesn't render after deployment ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app and for each page I use  component. All works as expected in the local "npm start", however, when I run a server from the build, the header on two particular pages are static and don't have interactions at all.
localhost:8080 - npm start
localhost:3000 - local server build

on the npm start you can see how the header looks like
[image]

while this is the same page but on the local server build. My mouse is also at the first button's hover, but its static at all and the logo is not rendering either.
[image]

and again the local build server but on the home page all works well
[image]

and some of my code
index.js

```
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route index element={<PrivateRoute><MainPage userid={userid} isAdmin={false} /></PrivateRoute>} />
                    <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<PrivateRoute><Product userid={userid} /></PrivateRoute>} />
                    <Route path="/cart" element={<PrivateRoute><Cart userID={userid} /></PrivateRoute>} />
                    {/* Use PublicRoute for the login page */}
                    <Route path="/login" element={<PublicRoute><Login /></PublicRoute>} />
                    <Route path="/order/:orderID" element={<PrivateRoute><Order userID={userid} /></PrivateRoute>} />
                    <Route path="/chat" element={<PrivateRoute><Chat /></PrivateRoute>} />
                    {/* Redirect users trying to access "/login" if they are already authenticated */}
                    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
        );
```

code snipper of /product/:id redirection:

```
    const items = products.slice(firstItemPage, lastItemPage).map((product, index) => (
        
        <div className={styles['grid-item']} key={product.id} onClick={() => navigate(`/product/${product.id}`)} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
          <div className={styles.picture}>
            ...
        </div>
    ));

    return (
        <div className={styles['grid-container']}>
            {items}
        </div>
    );
```

Render component for product.js

```
        return (
            <div className={styles.fullPage}>
                <Header isAdmin={false} />
                <ProductImages product={CurrentProduct} />
                <ProductDetails product={CurrentProduct} userID={userid} />
                <Comments product={CurrentProduct} />
                <AddReview product={CurrentProduct} setLoading={setLoading} />
                <Chat userid={userid} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';
import logo from './images/logo.jpg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function Header({isAdmin}) {
    return (
            <div className="headerBackground">
                <img className="logo" src={logo} />
                <ul className='navigationMenu'>
                {isAdmin && <Link to={`/admin`}><li className="cartButton"><a style={{color:"gold", fontWeight:"600"}}>АДМИН ПАНЕЛ</a></li></Link>}

                <Link to={`/`}><li><a>НАЧАЛО</a></li></Link>
                <Link to={`/`}><li><a>ЗА НАС</a></li></Link>
                <Link to={`/`}><li><a>ПРОФИЛ</a></li></Link>
                <Link to={`/cart`}><li className="cartButton"><a>КОЛИЧКА</a></li></Link>
                </ul>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Please, tell me what I am doing wrong as I don't really understand the problem. I used  instead of navigate, but even after changing it, the problem persists...

Comment: I don't see any header component code included in the [mcve] in your post, but if I had to guess it would seem that some assets are using relative URLs instead of absolute URLs and are thus not found when running your app when deployed. can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah, you are right, sorry about that. When you say some assets, why are the same assets okay in the main page but not for example in this case in the product page, when they are using the same component?

Comment: I only see the `MainPage` component rendered once. But to answer your question, it's because the URL is different than `"/"` when you are on a non-"home" page, so the browser uses the relative paths from *that* URL path instead of from root. BTW you still haven't shared the code that has the issue rendering the specific content.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, I am pretty tired already as well, is the header.js the component you need to see?

Comment: Yes, thank you. This appears to be a static image asset that is imported and built-in with the code instead of an image served from the public directory. What exactly is the difference in app "state/condition" between the first two screenshots? When you say "local server build" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Running `serve -s build` which deploys the react app from the build folder to a local server hosted on my PC. Nevertheless, I tried to deploy it into an Azure Web Application and it runs with the same result. And what exactly do you mean by "state/condition"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257138/discussion-between---and-drew-reese).

Comment: I mean, it looks like the same page, same URL, etc, in the first two screenshots.... so what *exactly* is different in the app between the two instances of it running? When the app is built does it include all the imported assets? I don't see anything wrong with the code you have shared so maybe there's an issue with the way the app is built or served.

Comment: @DrewReese we can also move to chat, but to answer your question, I don't think anything is really wrong with it. I just run `npm run build` and then tried to deploy my app, so I am not aware if I should have done something first. But then, the main page uses same `<Header />` and everything renders and interacts as expected...